# Starter spins but doesn't engage flywheel

Tags: ford, troubleshooting, starter, wiring, f-350

I was wondering if y'all could help me with this recurring problem.

My 1983 Ford F-350 has had a starter problem for the past couple of months. After a week or so of installing a new starter and solenoid the starter would begin to spin and not engage the flywheel.

I have had it tested at three different stores and it passes every time yet when installed in the car it stops working. I have replaced most of the ignition system related to the starter and I'm not sure if it's something I'm missing. There is an orange wire with a fusible link that has some wear - would that cause an issue like this?

Any suggestions on what to do? I have also replaced the solenoid on multiple occasions.

Comment: I think you've exhausted *electrical* possibilities. Time to start thinking *mechanical*.

Answer (score 4):

Its probably not the fuseable link;  more likely is that the starter motor needs to be shimmed.  The starter motor has a small gear ( the pinion gear) which sticks out on a shaft to engage the flywheel.  if the pinion gear doesn’t stick out far enough, it will spin but not turn the flywheel.  The starter will test fine on the bench.  Sometimes the pinion gear teeth are too high, so the gears don’t engage.  Shims are used to fine tune the positioning of the pinion gear.  I believe this was more necessary in older vehilcles (such as 1983 Fords....)
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help I'm going to head to an auto parts store and try that. I'll let you know how it works.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked it's the first time in months I've heard that 460 roar I really appreciate it